# Win32 api graphics in x86 assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, x86

I am trying to use the win32 api in x86 assembly to show graphics in a window. But I can't seem to find any tutorials/examples that does that. I did find a few tutorials that did this however they used other assemblers like MASM but I use NASM.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You can learn how the API works in an abstract way by looking at the MASM or even C examples by breaking things down to the basic blocks of memory operations, arithmetic operations, function calls and control flow and then write equivalent code in NASM.

Comment: @CherryDT The biggest problem for me is the x86 win32 syntax/functions. I already know a lot about the C api but I can't even find a single good tutorial/examples.

Comment: What you need is the calling conventions and for Windows, **stdcall**.

Comment: [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows). Compile that, and load it up in a disassembler, choosing the assembly dialect of your choice. [Calling conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/calling-conventions) explains why the calls are the way they are.

Comment: If you have a tutorial that doesn't use MASM's `invoke` magic, the instructions should be straightforward to translate to NASM syntax, if you know the major difference between it and MASM (in MASM, `mov eax, foo` is `mov eax, [foo]`, and you only get the address with `OFFSET foo`.)